# return non numeric charcter..show them in validation messages

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using validation on my jsp page . when an entry in a field is not acceptable we currently give generic error messages like "Please enter a valid number" but i want show like which character i have entered is not numeric. example:  suppose if I enter  "O" instead of an "0" , i want to show messages  "O" is not acceptable as number

How can I achieve this.Any ideas and guidelines would be appreciable

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is achieved easily. We all know we can use multiple validation messages in one property, right? Ex:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "link is wrong!")]
    [DisplayName("link (ex: http://test.com)")]
    [Url(ErrorMessage = "Please write a valid link!")]
    public string Linku { get; set; }
```

So, now all you have to do, is take some of your time and add as much as you need. You can add extra attribute on te previous example, and add one more case exactly as you needed it, ex:

```
    [RegularExpression("([a-zA-Z0-9 .&'-]+)", ErrorMessage = "You cant add numbers on the link field")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "link is wrong!")]
    [DisplayName("link (ex: http://test.com)")]
    [Url(ErrorMessage = "Please write a valid link!")]
    public string Linku { get; set; }
```

As i see, the main purpose of you is this attribute to take some parameter, and show him more dynamically on what he wrote, that is not right. But exaclty like that, attribute validation does not offer us something which is prepared. If we want to go that deep, we have to do it in our controller when we check:

```
 if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     //here we can edit validation error messages, since we can have 
     //parameters from the controller right?

  }
```

Also, you can check error messages, and maybe edit them inside this for loop.

```
        foreach (ModelState modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values) {
             foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors) {
                     DoSomethingWith(error);
    }
```

One more option is doing it with javascript/jquery, client side validation, which is not very useful when its up to security, and bypassing.

Comment: How does it show what is the char who generate the error ?

Comment: I am not sure about that, I couldn't get any deeper right now, maybe later bro. Just wanted a quick help with what I already now

Answer (score 0):

Here a quick exemple of how you can get all characters who dont fit your need. You may have to adapt it to your code. It is just a guideline.

```
String test="456464O1324l456";
    ArrayList<Character> chars=new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (Character c: test.toCharArray()) {
        boolean error=Character.isAlphabetic(c);
        if(error){
            chars.add(c);
        }
    }
    for (Character character : chars) {
        System.out.println(character);
    }
```